# WakaTime project map settings WIndows 11 and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, wakatime

I want to configure my projects in the `wakatime.cfg` file in the project map section. I am using Windows 11 and VSCode.
I already tried some things, but it's not working. In the WakaTime dashboard, it says “Unknown Project” no matter what I do.

My project paths are like

- `C:\Users\User\OneDrive - XXX\projects\test1` (Test Project 1)
- `C:\Users\User\OneDrive - XXX\projects\test2` (Test Project 2)
- `C:\Users\User\projects\project-1` (Project X)
- `C:\Users\User\projects\project-2` (Project Y)

How can I configure WakaTime to use these paths and names for my WakaTime dasboard?

Answer (score 2):

In your `~/.wakatime.cfg`:

```
[projectmap]
projects/test1 = Test Project 1
^C:/Users/User/OneDrive - XXX/projects/test1(\d+)/ = project{0}
projects/test2 = Test Project 2
^C:/Users/User/OneDrive - XXX/projects/test2(\d+)/ = project{0}
```

Alternatively:

Add a `.wakatime-project` file in each project folder, and inside that file, add that project's name

```sh
C:\Users\User\OneDrive - XXX\projects\test1
.wakatime-project (contains the text: Test Project 1)
C:\Users\User\OneDrive - XXX\projects\test2
.wakatime-project (contains the text: Test Project 2)
```

Why?

The [FAQ](https://wakatime.com/faq#create-projects) states:

WakaTime detects the project’s name these 3 ways:

1. Revision control software (git init)
2. A `.wakatime-project` file inside your root project folder. Type the project’s name as the first line of your .wakatime-project file and any future coding inside that folder will use the new project name.
3. A [`[projectmap]` section](https://github.com/wakatime/wakatime-cli/blob/develop/USAGE.md#project-map-section) in your `~/.wakatime.cfg` file matching a directory path.

```
[projectmap]
projects/foo = new project name
^/home/user/projects/bar(\d+)/ = project{0}
```

If that fails, rename `OneDrive - XXX` to `onedrive_xxx`